# UITabbarController firstly selected tab is behaving strangely

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have gone through a strange problem in `UITabbarController`. In my opinion this could be a bug.

This is my scenario,

I have a  `UITabbarController` with 4 tabs. Every tab is referring to different storyboards.

Now, in every storyboard in my initial `viewcontroller` there is two `containerview`. One is for topbar and one is for bottom navigation.

Now, in my initial `viewcontroller` I have set the bottom bar as `Translucent Tab Bar`. So there is a tabbar showing and I have set the constraint of bottom container with the tabbar.

So, now let's come to the strange situation that is arising:

When my app launches the first tab is selected and the `container`'s `viewcontrollers` are showing perfectly above `Tabbar`. But for all other tabs the
`container`'s `viewcontrollers` are going below `Tabbar`.

If I manually set the `selectedIndex` of `Tabbar` as 1 or 2 or 3 then the `container` on that tab is showing perfectly and the rest are behaving strange.

I am attaching screenshots for a better understanding.

This is my `UITabbarController`'s Storyboard:[image]

This is the design of all 4 tabs:[image]

Now for the first tab the `viewcontroller` is above tab bar but for rest it is going below tab bar and if I programmatically change the `selectedIndex` at the veru begining then the selectedTab's ViewController is showing perfectly and the rest is going below tabbar.

This is a screenshot of the Output when I have set selectedIndex as 1 instead of 0 at the beginning. As you can see it is showing above tabbar.
[image]

Now I have set the storyboard reference for the first tab is same as the second tab. Now see that for first tab the vc is going below tabbar.

[image]

If I set do not set selectedIndex, which means the default 0 index, the same thing is happening for the first tab, and the rest tabs are going below tabbar.

> Please Note that I have not written any codes instead of changing selectedIndex which is only for testing purpose.

Comment: Hi, it looks like first vc has selected checkmark Under Bottom Bars in extended edges section.

Comment: @AlexKosyakov: Hi, `Under Top Bar` and `Under Bottom Bar` is by default selected when we drag and drop a `viewcontroller` into our storyboard.

Comment: so, deselect it?

Comment: Ok I am doing that, but can you please tell me why the firstly selected tab and rest tabs are behaving different?

Comment: Cholbe na bhai ei shob noob question cholbe na!

Comment: @Saheb Roy: Thanks for your reply! But it's an`UITopbarController` bug.

Comment: If you think its a bug, then file report with apple, but i dont think its a bug, it must be something very basic you are missing, as the behaviour you are telling, is avoided by unselecting extended edges, if the container view is properly set with its superview's vc

Comment: Everything I understand, but when everything is same everywhere then why the tab that is selected at the very beginning is different from the rest tabs. This is my only question.

Comment: and it is not avoiding by unselecting the edge too. It still showing the same problem.

Comment: And When I am unselecting the `Under Bottom Bar` for both the container view controller as well as the child view controller then both the tabs behaving strangely.

Answer (score 1):

Try unsetting the **'Extend Edges Under Bottom Bars'** attribute of your Storyboard's Initial UIViewControllers.

[image: UIViewController Inspector]

Comment: These are selected. Default the first two are selected.

Comment: Have you tried unselecting the 'under bottom bars' ?

Comment: No I havent, but why only the first tab which will be shown is behaving strangely. That same viewcontroller is working perfectly for other tabs.

Comment: I have deselected the `Under Bottom Bars`. But Now When I am going further on navigation, a black portion is showing below.

Comment: That black portion of the screen is the portion of the unaccounted space, while taking into account of the container's view controller.

Comment: But, the view controller which is selected at first only that tab is behaving strangely.